# Flex Dictionary: Order

Tags: apache-flex

Does Flex Dictionary maintain the order of its elements?

Comment: how are you accessing the elements?

Answer (score 5):

From 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_4.html

> Associative arrays are unordered
>   collections of key and value pairs.
>   Your code should not expect the keys
>   of an associative array to be in a
>   specific order.

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary maintains no order of items and does not provide information about the number of elements contained.

U can access it as any other key-value structure